# class 'product' has no 'objects' member

Tags: python, django

File `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class customer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200 )
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=200 )
    email= models.CharField(max_length=200 )
    data_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def _self_(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200 )
    def _self_(self):
        return self.name

class product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY= (
            ('Indoor','Indoor'),
            ('Out Door', 'Out Door'),
        )
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category =models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description =models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags= models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class order(models.Model):
    STATUS= (
            ('Pending','Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivery','Delivery'),
        )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customer,null=True , on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, null=True , on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status =models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True, choices=STATUS)
```

File `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')

def products(request):
    products= product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'products.html',{'products':products})

def customer(request):
    return render(request, 'customer.html')
```

The errors:

1. Class 'product' has no 'objects' member pylint(no-member)[9,15].
2. function already defined line 3 pylint(function-redefined) [12,3].

Comment: Did you run the migration command

Comment: yes i have done that bro ...

Comment: Please add some more context to your question, paste the full traceback, here's a link how you can ask a better question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Isn't this just a warning from your linter that cannot follow django's magic?

Comment: run the server and look whether this error affect the run

Comment: use [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) or [pylint-django](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/). These are just warning about linting problem. You may configure your linter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues are just warnings from your Linter that is not following Django internal behavior (`objects` is a method that is coming from the Django class your `product` class is inheriting from). Install [Pylint django](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/)